# Thinking sphinx stuck on a port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

A number of applications are running on the same machin with sphinx & TS running.

Unfortunately I had on application with the same search port as another application that was launched after.  The older application was not searching properly to say the least.

I fucked up and set it to 9314, which ought to be servicing and older rails 2 application.

I changed the port anew

```
  mysql41: 9311
```

and the new port does not seem to register for thinking-Sphinx.  But now

```
rake:ts:start
```

fails because searchd cannot be started. The log states:

```
listening on 127.0.0.1:9314
```

tried various free ports to no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run ts:configure or ts:index (which runs ts:configure itself) to ensure the configuration file is regenerated (and thus has the latest port setting). Once you've done that, then ts:start should use 9311.

Comment: Yep. I had wondered why the log referenced the change to a second port, but the would not go further.  I had certainly used ts:index.  Then for some reason stopped.  Good to know that `index` runs `configure`! THank you Pat!